# In a tree Parent and Child Check and uncheck combination in SWT in java

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am implementing a tree. This tree has five `treecolumn`, in between five `treecolumn` first column by default selected checkbox at the time of designing.

Now I am creating two `treeitem` 1st one parent and second one child. All the data getting from DB in this `treeItem`.

if I select parent checkbox, automatically all child checkbox should be selected.[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muBql.png)

if I uncheck parent, all child should be unchecked. How can I overcome this situation?

Comment: Providing some code and pointint more specific what you don't understand significantly increases your chances to get a good answer

Comment: It is up to you to listen to the check events and write code to check / uncheck the children.

Comment: Also are you using `CheckboxTreeViewer` or just `Tree`?

Comment: using Tree only

Comment: Tree remoteTable = new Tree(composite_1, SWT.BORDER | SWT.CHECK | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.VIRTUAL);
  remoteTable.setBounds(0, 0, 530, 411);
  remoteTable.setHeaderVisible(true);
  
  TreeColumn trclmnNewColumn = new TreeColumn(remoteTable, SWT.NONE);
  trclmnNewColumn.setWidth(121);
  trclmnNewColumn.setText("TestSuite/TestCase");

Comment: Take a look at this example: [www.javadocexamples.com - Tree5](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/part1/ch9/Tree5.java.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3300205/avojak thanks it works. it's really helpfull for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> parent item checked or unchecked to all child item checked or unchecked using tree in eclipse rcp (Java).

```
tree.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
      public void handleEvent(Event event) {
       if (event.detail == SWT.CHECK) {
        TreeItem item = (TreeItem) event.item;
        boolean checked = item.getChecked();
        checkItems(item, checked);
        }
     }
});
```

> checkItems() method two arguments first tree item and second boolean value checked or not

```
static void checkItems(TreeItem item, boolean checked) {
     item.setGrayed(false);
     item.setChecked(checked);
     TreeItem[] items = item.getItems();
     for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        checkItems(items[i], checked);
     }
}
```